# Can I preserve the appearance of the input XML with Transolution?

Tags: xml, xsd, localization, xliff

I'm just opening a `source.xlf`, setting a couple of strings to translated, and saving it as `dest.xlf`, and it happens that the XMLs have lots of modifications:

- Tag attributes are written out a in different order, actually alphabetically.
- Tags such as `<note></note>` are written out as `<note/>`
- `<xliff version="1.2">` is written out in a new line.

Is there a way of telling Transolution not to do these modifications? Maybe using a schema?

Comment: No idea what "Transolution" is, but regardless, none of the variations you mention are significant in XML.  No conformant XML software will care, and neither should you.

Comment: @kjhughes Transolution is an Xliff editor. I care because, when I compare source and destination files, I only want to see real, significative changes, no ordering changes, or tag formatting changes. The same if I were to upload those files to a repository; I wouldn't want to upload those "ordering" changes.

Comment: You have it backwards.  Don't fight the XML standard because you want to use a text-based comparison tool; use an XML-based comparison tool instead.  Use the right tool for the job.

Comment: @kjhughes hehe I was thinking of that too when I replied to you earlier; it's not just the diff tool; it's the SVN repository too; and there can be more; it's the idea of configuring two systems the same way so that they generate the same output, eliminating the need of an extra phase of sorting or reformatting (by two systems that generate XML I mean a, my system which generates the source.xlf, and b, the Xliff editor which generates the dest.xlf)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like a dead project to me.
http://sourceforge.net/projects/eviltrans/files/

Get a professional tool like Trados. They have a cheap $90 version for freelancers.
Or some online solution like http://www.translate5.net/

`<note></note>` written as `<note/>` is correct.
`<xliff version="1.2">` written on a new line is fine too.

The sequence should stay the same.

Comment: Thanks. I'm accepting this answer as it is the only one, and it looks quite fair to me.